# Applying templates after key lookup

Tags: xml, xslt

I have an XML file like so:

```
<root>
 <texts>
   <text id='1' lang='en'>Hello <name/>, how are you today?</text>
   <text id='1' lang='de'>Hallo <name/>, wie geht es Ihnen heute?</text>
 </texts>
 <items>
   <item textId='1'><name>Some Name</name></item>
 </items>
</root>
```

What I need to do is to get a text with the name filled out after selecting a language. What I have come up with so far:

```
  <xsl:variable name="lang" select="'de'" />

  <xsl:key name="textKey" match="text" use="@id" />

  <xsl:template match="items">
    <xsl:value-of select="key('textKey', @text)[@lang=$lang]"/>
  </xsl:template>
```

Now I don't know how to replace the 'name' in the 'text' nodes? Does anyone know how to do it?

Comment: That's not a well-formed input XML - should be `<name/>` I suppose? A complete stylesheet and the expected output would also be helpful - see [mcve].

Comment: I'm sorry, I have fixed the XML issues.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try something like::

```
<xsl:variable name="lang" select="'de'" />

<xsl:key name="textKey" match="text" use="concat(@id, '|', @lang)" />

<xsl:template match="item">
    <xsl:apply-templates select="key('textKey', concat(@textId, '|', $lang))">
        <xsl:with-param name="name" select="."/>
    </xsl:apply-templates>
</xsl:template>

<xsl:template match="text">
    <xsl:param name="name"/>
    <xsl:apply-templates>
        <xsl:with-param name="name" select="$name"/>
    </xsl:apply-templates>
</xsl:template>

<xsl:template match="name">
    <xsl:param name="name"/>
    <xsl:value-of select="$name"/>
</xsl:template>
```

Comment: Thank you for your reply. How would that work if the thing to be replaced were in the middle of the sentence like for example: "Hello <name/>, how are you?"

Comment: I have run into a new problem... how would this work, if you would have multiple types of tags you need to replace? say not just <name/>, but <firstName/>, <lastName/>, <birthday/?>

Comment: The same way: pass the values as parameters and create a template for each element. Note that this can be slightly simplified in XSLT 2.0 + with its "tunnel" parameter.

Comment: Thanks. It works now, the "tunnel" parameter makes it a lot nicer.